# Prove that $|x(a)| + \max \{|x'(t)|: t \in [a,b]\}$ is a norm for a complete space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

> Prove that the space $C^1([a,b])$ consisting of continuous functions in $[a, b]$ with the norm $|x(a)| + \max \{|x'(t)|: t \in [a,b]\}$ is a Banach space.

I can't prove the completeness of this space. Hope someone can help me. Thanks. I really appreciate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not even a norm.  Take $a = 0$, $b=1$, $x(t) = -2 + 2t$.  Did you mean "$|x(a)|$"?  By the way, "\max" gives you $\max$ and is easier on the eyes.

EDIT: after I wrote the above, the question was fixed and "$x(a)$" was replaced by "$|x(a)|$", so the given norm (I'll call it "$\| \cdot \|_l$") actually is a norm.  The norm $\| \cdot \|_l$ is equivalent to the standard norm on $C^1([a,b])$, which is $\|f\| = \max_{[0,1]} |f| + \max_{[0,1]} |f'|$: to verify this you must verify two inequalities, one of which is trivial, and the other one of which takes a little work.  Then a sequence of functions $(f_n) \subset C^1([0,1])$ is Cauchy in one of the norms if and only if it is Cauchy in the other norm.  If you are allowed to assume $C^1([0,1])$ is complete using the standard norm, it should be easy to prove $C^1([0,1])$ is complete using $\| \cdot \|_l$.

Comment: Let me check it again. It's the problem in my functional analysis class. But thanks anyway Stefan

Comment: By the way, is the problem right if we change from $x(a)$ into $|x(a)|$?

Comment: @leducquang : I added to my answer and I hope it helps.  I also replaced "$C'([a,b])$" with "$C^1([a,b])$ because the latter is standard, and "norms" with "norm" in your question.

Comment: Thanks so much Stefan. You're kind.